# Not able to put columns within the same row by Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am newbie for bootstrap and now creating a website to with one row and two columns.

Everything just did well before I add an image to the column. After I add an image, the column just break to the next line. Could anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Please take a look at this image:
[image]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="product-info col-sm-6" style="margin-left:-15px;">
    <?= $this->Html->image($product->name.'.jpg',['class'=>'img-responsive') ?>
</div>
<div class="product-info col-sm-6 offset-sm-6">
    <span><?= $product->category->category ?></span><br>
    <span><?= $product->name ?></span><br>
    <span>￥<?= $product->price ?></span><br>
</div>
```

I have just tried using `margin-left:-15px;`, but nothing help.

Comment: Did you inspect in firebug and see the issue?

Comment: I made changes. Please check.If any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. i will share you link as well. Please check. If any changes please let me know. Just remove **offset-sm-6**.As well as you need add css for img tag. You just give **img tag to width:100%; and height: auto**. Your problem will solve.

https://jsfiddle.net/ah7q9fmc/

```css
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    col-sm-6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It perfectly solved my problem.
But may I ask why offset do not work with img tag?

Comment: @fcy_brian Please accept the answer to close this question

Comment: @fcy_brian Actually there is no need of offset. Offsets are used for spacing elements in the responsive grid

Comment: @fcy_brian if i am right then please give me feedback.